# two different actions on same button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am developing one simple demo application for room reservation
where I have three tables as member_types, customers, and donors

The models are as follows

```
class MemberType < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one  :donor
 has_many :customers
 has_many :room_rates
 attr_accessible :member_type
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member_type 
  has_one  :donor
  has_many :rooms
  has_many :room_types
  has_many :room_rates
end

class Donor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :member_type 
  attr_accessible :donation, :free_days, :used_days,:customer_id
end
```

I have added member_types as donor, guest and two other as admin 
when customers add their basic info with select member_type as donor and submitting it stores all info in the customer table

How can I add this customer_id in donor table when customer submit their info?

Comment: Can you show me your controller when customer submits their info? (create, update)

Comment: actually i am using devise for customer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use active record callback in Customer model, something like this:

```
class Customer< ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :new_donor

  private 
  def new_donor
    new_record = Donor.new(:customer_id => self.id)
    new_record.save
  end

end
```

Btw, you have a closed loop relation in your model design (room_rates is belongs to member_type and customer) which is not a best practice in table design although it's not totally wrong either. 
If possible, you may want to redesign it

Comment: It was guessing answer, well just like @Francois asked, could you provide the method when customer submit their info